# navbar brand and other navigation menu on same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap `navbar` in my app.

I want to align the `brand` and Its other navigation menu on the right side.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-order-mgmt" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Order Management</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
    <a href = "#">Products</a>
    <a href = "#">Orders</a>
    <a href = "#">Expenses</a>
        </li>
    </ul>   
  </div>
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/rhku2qvj/) is what I have at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in css

```
 .navbar-header button.navbar-brand {float:left;}
 .navbar-header ul {float:right;margin:0;padding:0;}
 ul {list-style:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
```